# Node name mismatch when trying to access publicly exposed RabbitMQ through Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to access a publicly exposed RabbitMQ running in a EKS Kubernetes cluster

The Load Balancer Service was created and works properly (I'm able to connect to the exposed port using telnet)

The problem is that when I try to connect to RabbitMQ using a CLI tool I get:

`Node name (or hostname) mismatch: node "rabbit@shared-service-rabbitmq-0.shared-service-rabbitmq-headless.shared.svc.cluster.local" believes its node name is not "rabbit@some-domain.com" but something else`

I didn't find a way to change the hostname or the node name using the Helm chart

I'm pretty sure that the solution is something really simple but I'm spending many hours researching and I still don't see how to fix this

Could someone please point me to the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you using cluster of rabbitmq with multiple nodes?

Comment: No, it's not a cluster with multiple nodes